# Flash FlowPlayer crossdomain.xml error

Tags: flash, jquery-plugins, mp3, crossdomain.xml, flowplayer

I posted a problem I'm having with the FlowPlayer jQuery plugin at http://static.flowplayer.org/forum/1/29367, but I've had no response, so I thought I'd try the larger user base here... :)

I am having a problem with crossdomain.xml and the audio plugin to play an mp3.

The player loads ok but I get an error like this when I click the Play button. When I click Continue the MP3 file loads and plays. The error comes up once more so I click Continue and all is ok. How can I stop the errors coming up?

SecurityError: Error #2122: Security sandbox violation: Sound.id3:http://www.XXXXXX.com/global/swf/flowplayer.audio-3.1.2.swf cannot accesshttp://serving.XXXXXX.com/assets/podcast.mp3. A policy file is required, but the checkPolicyFile flag was not set when this media was loaded.
    at flash.media::Sound/get id3()
    at org.flowplayer.audio::AudioProvider/onId3()

My crossdomain.xml in the root of serving.XXXXXX.com is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<cross-domain-policy xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="http://www.adobe.com/xml/schemas/PolicyFile.xsd">
    <allow-access-from domain="*" />
</cross-domain-policy>
```

Thanks,
Tim

Answer (score -1, accepted):

http://static.flowplayer.org/forum/1/29367

Comment: Looks like they've moved the forum unfortunately, and I can't find a copy, nor can I now delete this post.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try using *.xxxxx.com instead of only *? I have also had experiences where crossdomain does not work testing locally but operates just fine from a web server.